# Visual Studio 2012 throwing error while building website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, hresult

I am getting the errors below while building an ASP.NET website in Visual Studio 2012 over and over again. These errors are very random and sometimes I'm able to run the site after many attempts.

> 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
> Files\fccrcissues\94bcbaf1\224612b9\CSC7282803B8D0F44FBA57E415444603873.TMP'
> is not a valid Win32 resource file
>
> The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))

The only solution I have is to build it over and over again until it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Had a same problem! Try this. Have given link to solution too.

1st Solution) Under you IIS > Virtual Directory Properties > Execution Permissions might be marked as “Scripts and Executables” the dll is not being loaded so you are  getting “System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException”

Try changing the Execution Permissions to “Scripts Only” and applying it - It should work now!

I am not sure about the exact different between the two so all I know is:

Scripts only  -> Run only scripts,such as ASP applications  and
Scripts and Executables -> Run both scripts, such as ASP applications, and executables

2nd Solution) On your server where you're website sits, open the command prompt and run the following command:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i - It should work now!

http://www.strivingprogrammers.com/How-to-fix-The-handle-is-invalid-Exception-from-HRESULT-0x80070006-E-HANDLE